# How can I run crone Trigger immediately using crone expression in java?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Below is my code, I want to run my job every ten minutes by crone expression.
I want the first time my job run immediately after that it should run on 10 minutes interval.I am using quartz-2.1.2

```
JobKey jobKeyA = new JobKey("abc", "abc");

JobDetail jobA = JobBuilder.newJob(ContiniousJob.class)
        .withIdentity(jobKeyA).build();

Trigger trigger3 = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("abc", "abc")
        .startNow()
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/10  * * * ?"))
        .build();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CronTrigger if you just want 10 minutes interval, you can just use SimpleTrigger:

```
Trigger trigger3 = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("abc", "abc")
        .startNow()
        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInMinutes(10)
            .repeatForever())
        .build();
```

If you **still** need to use CronTrigger for any reason, this should work:

```
// Trigger to run immediately
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("abc", "abc")
            .startNow()
            .build(); 
Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<>();
triggers.add(trigger);

// Your CronTrigger
Date delayedStart = DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(), 10); 
Trigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("abc", "abc")
        .startAt(delayedStart)
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/10  * * * ?"))
        .build();

triggers.add(cronTrigger);

// Schedule job with multiple triggers
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, triggers, false);
```

One trigger to run immediately, another one to be your CronTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no chances to fire cron rightaway.
I have suggestion to schedule task right after when it needs to be launched with a some short delay period (current time + 1 minute).
Try to test your expression [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/).